# Шашка — оружие, дымовая шашка и игральная

Tags: омонимы

У слова "шашка" много значений: и холодное оружие, и дымовая шашка, и игральная фишка. Это просто случайное совпадение или нет?
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

http://omop.su/article/79/1935.html

ша́шка I "холодное оружие"-от кабард.-черкес. са`шхо-длинный нож.

II ша́шка II "шашечная фигура", первонач. "шахматная фигура, королева". производное от др.-русск. шахы мн. "шахматы", древнее заимствование из перс.(шах-король);

III ша́шка III "любовница", перм. (Даль), сиб. (ЖСт., 1899, вып. 4, 516). Вероятно, первонач. тождественно предыдущему, т. е. "королева (в шахматах)".
Источник: Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс, М. Р. Фасмер, 1964—1973 гг.http://otvazhnyi.livejournal.com/80793.html

Шахматы делали из дерева, в русск. яз. было ещё одно значение - всякий  мелкий отрубочек, отрезочек, кубик, отсюда - кость игральная, с очками;отсюда же и толовая шашка - брусок с начинкой, всё, похожее на брусок, хоть цилиндрический,  хоть кубический, хоть параллелепипед, - шашка. Теперь  у нас и шашки от тараканов, и медицинские шашки - всё шашки.

Шашник, легкое дерево, ветла, осокорь, из которого режутся шашки на поплавки.

шашка - ткань, клетчатая, как доска под шашки

шашня - расстановка чего-то,как в шашках и шахматах

Шашни -  интриги, проделки плутовские происки, происки сообща - как в шахматах и шашках.

Comment: >шашня - расстановка чего-то,как в шашках и шахматах

Это как? В шахматах и шашках совершенно разные расстановки. И в русских и стоклеточных шашках все игровые фигуры расположены по диагоналям, на чёрных полях, а в шахматах в две шеренги, где в первой - стоят пешки, а за ними - фигуры, включая короля.

Comment: Но общий смысл: две команды строго друг против друга на доске в клеточку. А шашни - уже от хитроумных ходов,ведущих к победе.

Comment: Да, с "шашней" тут что-то дюже экзотическое получилось...
Никаких мыслей не приходит, что это за расстановка такая.
В волейболе, например, - это шашня? 0_o?!
С остальным - согласен.

Comment: Экзотическое, потому что южный диалект: У Даля-http://slovari.299.ru/word.php?id=43373 
"- расстановка чего, шахматная, один ряд супротив промежутков другого, вразбежку".

Comment: Нет, не "потому что диалект", а потому, что непонятно, к чему относится. Очеренной ляп Даля. "Один ряд ***супротив промежутков*** другого" - это еще можно как-то как-то свести к шашкам, но никак не к шахматам.   
А все, думается, проще. Шахматная доска (чередование белых и черных клеток) называется шашечницей - тут уж не поспоришь. Или шашней. Как и сама расстановка чего-либо "в шашечку". Сравните с использование для названия "шашечки" для символа такси.

Answer (score 0):

Весь список я не рискну сейчас комментировать...
Есть мысли по поводу двух вещей.
Фасмер (вслед за Далем) явно смешивает шашки и шахматы. А между тем русские шашки гораздо древнее известности шахмат на Руси.

ша́шка (игральная фишка) Очень сомнительно, что королеву звали "шашкой". По её сути. 
Вообще исходно ферзь ("королева") считалась визирем при короле (шахе). Понмится было и какое-то соответствующее русское слово. Не помню. Что-то типа "Витязя". Но не "шахмата" точно.
С другой стороны есть смутое подозрение, что "шашкой" назывался любой невысокий кругляш.

По поводу шахмат вообще - что-то сомнительное, что это множественное от Шах. На арабское тоже не похоже... С лругой стороны "Мат" по-турецки "смерть"(возможно, и на фарси тоже). Что вполне объясняет и шахматную терминологию - и его название.

шашка (заряд) - подозреваю (не утверждаю!), что заимствование, возможно - из  немецкого. Перенесение на заряд названий для круглых фишек весьма сомнительно.
Название для всякие современных зарядов (типа антикомариных) могло развиться из этого значения.